# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser'

Tags: ios, swift

Working on iOS multipeer connectivity, after updating to Swift 2.0, facing issue with following codes:

```
var advertiser:MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
var peer:MCPeerID!

func startEndAdvertising(value:Bool)
{
     if advertiser == nil
     {
         var someObject: [String : AnyObject] = ["profileName" : DataCentral.getInstance.userPeerVO.peerName]
         advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peer, discoveryInfo: someObject, serviceType: "shadow-chat")
         advertiser.delegate = self
     }
 }
```

This following line generates error as "Cannot invoke initialiser for type 'MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser' with an argument list of type '(peer: MCPeerID!, discoveryInfo: [String : AnyObject], serviceType: String)'"

```
advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peer, discoveryInfo: someObject, serviceType: "shadow-chat")
```

Comment: `var someObject: [String : AnyObject] ` => `var someObject: [String : String] ` ? Since in the doc it's: `init(peer myPeerID: MCPeerID, discoveryInfo info: *[String : String]*?, serviceType serviceType: String)`

Comment: I tried. But this not worked for me.

Comment: Direct use of the Dictionary object to MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser did solved my problem somehow, though: `advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peer, discoveryInfo: ["profileName" : DataCentral.getInstance.userPeerVO.peerName], serviceType: "shadow-chat")`